# Javascript not running in chrome app in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web application that has to do with key pressing. It is functioning well across all browsers except for Chrome in mobile.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function O000OOO(e) {
    var O0000O0;
    if (window.event) {
        if (window.event.type == "keypress") {
            O00OO00 = -1
        }
        if (window.event.type == "keypress") {
            O00OO00 = window.event.keyCode
        }
        if (parseInt(O00OO00) > 0) {
            O0000O0 = O00OO00
        } else {
            O0000O0 = window.event.keyCode
        }
    } else {
        if (e.type == "keypress") {
            O00O0OO = e.which;
            O00OO00 = -1
        }
        if (e.type == "keypress") {
            O00OO00 = e.which
        }
        if (parseInt(O00OO00) > 0) {
            O0000O0 = O00OO00
        } else {
            if ((parseInt(O00O0OO) > 0) && (e.which < 1)) {
                O0000O0 = O00O0OO
            } else {
                O0000O0 = e.which
            }
        }
    }
    return (parseInt(O0000O0))
}
```

and 000000 is a string.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: What code? You forgot to post it

Comment: I don't think today is April 1st. Who came up with functions and variables named `O000OOO`, `O0000O0`,`O00OO00`(which is not declared here)? Code is supposed to be readable, and this clearly isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `beforeinput` event rather then `keypress` as it looks like keypress is depreciated so may not be supported. Have a look at this from w3:

https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#determine-keypress-keyCode

They specify partway through that:

> Authors SHOULD use the `beforeinput` event instead of the keypress
>   event

So that is pretty clear.